# Object is initialized before constructor's execution

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

I want to execute the code present in constructor before object initialization.  Since object is initialize with some parameter, so the parameter carry it's values.

Calling function :

```
ABC as = new ABC (driver );
```

After Object initialization from calling function. "driver " value is passed to ABC constructor. But instead of executing code inside constructor ie  `this.driver= driver;`  . It jumps to initialized object of `XYZ class` . Due to which parameter of `XYZ class` has null value ie `driver=null`

```
public class ABC {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public ABC(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        System.out.println("**********");
    }

    XYZ st = new XYZ(driver);
}
```

Comment: Instance fields are initialized before the constructor is run. That's how it works. Add `st = new XYZ(driver);` at the end of your constructor code

Comment: What is preventing you from initialising XYZ in the constructor?

Comment: Hi @Antopn , since      this.driver = driver;     line is not executed . driver of XYZ class has null

Comment: @ ernest_k , Thanks a lots your suggestion  works for me